# jQuery.countdown not actually outputting

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

my countdown timer isn't actually printing anything to the span/div, I really would like some insight as to why, I have tried multiple ways of doing it but none have worked.

My code:

```
<div id='att-<?php echo $rowID; ?>'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#att-<?php echo $rowID; ?>").countdown({
        until : <?php echo abs(time()-($show['date']+$show['time'])); ?>,
        layout : " in {hn} {hl}, {mn} {ml} and {sn} {sl}",
        onExpiry : function () {
                        $("#att-<?php echo $rowID; ?>").html("Boot finished");
                        $("tr.boot-<?php echo $rowID; ?>").delay(6666).fadeOut();
                        }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please change your code and remove the `<?php ?>` tags and replace them by dummy data? It will make your code a lot more readable.

Comment: Could you also provide a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?